# Strategy for memory-efficiently mapping int arrays to integer

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

My code generates large amounts of integer vectors (in the millions) that need to be mapped to integer numbers (meaning the same arrays have to correspond with the same integers). The context is that the integer numbers correspond with rows in a (sparse) matrix, and the arrays thus correspond with identifiers of linear equations.

Currently, my method of mapping requires much more memory (in the gigabytes) than the storage of the matrix, which is the actual relevant object. I'm looking for a memory efficient method of mapping these arrays.

Some facts about the arrays:

1. They are of varying lengths, but always multiples of two.
2. The values of the elements of the arrays are relatively small. All odd elements are in approximately [-5,5] while all even elements are in approximately [0,150].

I have tried:

1. A regular `map<array, int>`
2. A tree structure of objects that can carry the corresponding integer

Is there an alternative? I am currently much less concerned with computing time than with memory usage.

Comment: what exactly do you mean mapping? in common sense, if your equation does not changed, it's better to represent as simple array. then, if you use hash function to map, how would you suffer from memory problem? it should be time consumption problem instead.

Comment: I just mean I have to link every unique array with a unique integer. I don't understand how a hash function would help me. The result of a hash function still has to be stored, and those hashes are likely larger than the arrays, right?

Comment: no, the result of a hash function should be a 4-byte integer.

Comment: Then how does the mapping work? If you calculate a 4-byte integer for every array, you will surely find the same integer for different arrays.

Comment: What about having a pool of arrays, where each array has an associated handle. Creating a new array in that pool is allocating a new handle, compare it to existing array handles and drop the new handle, if the array exists. In other words some map<ArrayHandle, ArrayIdentifier> (which is a set)

Comment: What about a mathematical function for the given array? That way you don't have to map instead you calculate the int value for that array. Perhaps if you treat each array as an Euclidian vector and use the distance and angle for generate the int value.

Comment: yes, it's possible. but if you calculate the possibility, and you implement a proper way to calculate the hash value, it's pretty hard to collide. i think you may need 2^20~30 different arrays to find a collision.

Comment: @Dieter I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by a handle?

Comment: @Raydel Miranda, yes this would be very useful, but I haven't been able to think of such a function. Is there some standard option I don't know about?

Comment: the common conclusion is that, if A and B share the same hash code, they are equal to each other with high possibility, as long as you don't have the ridiculous number of arrays i have mentioned. but still, as i said, you should implement it well.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, is there a standard hash function that can be used for integer arrays? I have a very serious problem if two different arrays are mapped to the same integer, so I assume I'd need a very clever hash function for this.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, I understand that Euclidian vectors are uniquely defined by their length and angle, but that description requires as many integers as are included in the array initially (1 length and N-1 angles).

Comment: well, there indeed are some common strategy for hashing. it's better for you to read online in details. i am pretty sure that you won't find collision in 1000 equations. actually, i think it's still a good idea to use hash table. hash code is not what you want. just define a class, implement a hash function, then use map.

Comment: @RobVerheyen I edited my comment. I meant to use that length and that angle for generate the int value. Since the range of values in your array's elements are small -5 - 150. You sure find a function that give unique values for unique array/vector.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, I don't understand what you mean. There is not a single angle associated with a Euclidian vector, but N-1 angles. It is just a change of coordinate system.

Comment: @RobVerheyen do you need persist this map?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda not sure what you mean. I dont need the map anymore after Im done generating arrays.

Comment: @RobVerheyen Sorry my last comment is that I come out with an idea but then I  realized it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobVerheyen you could look into a cryptographic hash function like SHA-1 or MD5. These are meant to work on arbitrary data and will give an evenly distributed corresponding number and have a very low probability of collision. MD5 gives a 128 bit hash and SHA-1 gives a 160 bit hash.

Comment: @RobVerheyen and by very low probability of collision I mean there are no known collisions with SHA-1, and there are only one or two with MD5.

Comment: This isn't a mapping problem, it is a compression problem.  You need a more compact representation for your data that a vector of ints.  Evening using hashing you'd still need to keep the original representation around in case of collisions.  It is hard to provide much help with the compression without a more exact description of the vectors (no "approximately")  Maybe create your own class to represent the data, the play with different schemes internally to that class.